How do i implement audio in my code in HTML
Heres my code :
 <audio loop autoplay> <source src="song.mp3" type = "audio/mpeg"> </audio>
my "song" folder is saved in the same directory as the code file , so that cant be the issue ,the problem is that the song isnt running in the background as i want it to .
its very frustrating cus i havent really found anything in terms of troubleshooting ; can somebody please help!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Please share the errors you see in console

"the song isnt running in the background as i want it to" – generally autoplay won't work, because otherwise every site under the sun would be abusing it to autoplay music in the background.


    
    Your browser does not support the audio element.

If you write a code like above, it will solve all errors that you were facing.
This code:

Adding muted resolves autoplay restrictions.
The./ ensures the correct file path is used.
Testing the file ensures it’s properly encoded.


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
